# Difference between Document and Query in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

According to the mongoose documentation:

Mongoose models provide several static helper functions for CRUD operations. Each of these functions returns a mongoose **Query** object.

**Models** are fancy constructors compiled from Schema definitions.

Mongoose documents represent a one-to-one mapping to documents as stored in MongoDB. Each **document** is an instance of its Model.

Now, all the static CRUD functions on the Model return a Query. However, in the documents section, under guides, it says "When you load documents from MongoDB using model functions like findOne(), you get a Mongoose document back.".

At one place Model.findOne() is returning a Query object and at a different section its returning a document...Can someone please help explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really a good question.
Simply creating a query doesn't mean loading the document from the Model. When you use `findOne()` method you just create a query, it will return `Query Object`. When you execute this query to load the document from the model, in this case the return is a `document Object`. Hope the following example will clarify the idea, knowing that this is not the only way to execute the query.

The first part is to create the query

```
    const query = myModel.findOne({ name })
    console.log(query.constructor.name) // Query
    console.log(query instanceof mongoose.Query) // True
    console.log(query instanceof mongoose.Document) // False
```

The second part is to execute it

```
    query.then((document) => {
        console.log(document.constructor.name) // model
        console.log(document instanceof mongoose.Query) // False
        console.log(document instanceof mongoose.Document) // True
        response.json(document)
    }).catch((error) => {
        response.json(error)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I read @Aya Othman's answer several times and understood it only after reading the Mongoose documents a few times. So I thought maybe noobs like myself need a bit different explanation. As I understood, we know that Mongoose [models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) have several functions for [CRUD operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) such as `Model.find()`, `Model.findById()`, `Model.findByIdAndDelete()`, etc. For example, when `User.findById(userId)` function is invoked without keyword `await` it doesn't fetch the user from the database and return document but it returns a query. This query is an object. It has methods. Now if we want to fetch the user we can call `exec()` method of the query.

```
const query = User.findById(userId)

// fetch only user's name and age
query.select("name age")

// execute query at a later time
// `await query.exec()` is equivalent to `await User.findById(userId)`
const user = await query.exec()
console.log(user instanceof mongoose.Document) // true
```

For further details I recommend reading about [Queries](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) and [Documents](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html).